# Repainting buildings' exterior, but with a different color

Tags: repainting

Is there an advantage to repaint the exterior of a home the same color?  What considerations need be made to pick a very different color?  We have 13 buildings in a condominium that are painted brownish tan.  There is movement here to repaint all buildings grey instead of the original color.  Would we incur more expense to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue of coverage. Using the same color means you don't have to be quite as picky/concerned about even coverage/multiple coats.

That said, if you're hiring out, a professional painter should be fine handling a repaint no matter the underlying color.

Comment: If there is a home owners association check with them first!  My step dad painted a condo , after all the prep and putting a non brown/green the owners had to have him do the unit again. Luckily he did a good on all the prep and used good paint so the required color covered in 1 coat. Dad made more but the owners were forced to paint the white/blue with green/brown , hope you don't have these crazy rules but it can cost if you don't check or know!

Comment: Regarding coverage, the brand and quality of paint make a huge difference. Spend more for premium paint and you can reasonably expect to cover with one coat, or one coat plus an immediate re-roll. Cheap, watery paint may appear to cover with two coats and still leave you with a finish that lets the original color affect its final hue.